# How to authenticate from one domain to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have to website,one of theme is main site and another is for my company services
user must register in firs website and can use my services in another site.

another website is a sub domain in first.

```
now i have a question, how can i move user 
log in authentication after user log in, in first site to second site?

 what is the best and secure way?
```

i user form authentication in first site to authenticate my users and user validate in first site's database.
my firs site is in mvc3 razor and .net4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the domain on the authentication cookie to just the TLD without the www etc?

Example, mysite.com rather than www.mysite.com.  I believe that means it will be visible to all sub domains too, so admin.mysite.com will see the cookie from mysite.com.

You will need to ensure that if you use an encrypted cookie, that each app has the same machine key to be able to decrypt it.

[Here is a post describing it](http://forums.asp.net/t/1533660.aspx/1)

Si

Answer (score 0):

For that type of architecture you want to use a [federated token service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347547.aspx).  For .NET 4.0 you can use [Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dd440951.aspx) to create this type of security.  WIF is built in to .NET 4.5 and has been improved. I would move to .NET 4.5 if that is an option.